# How to not let gSoap add "USCORE" after each underscore in a field's name?

Tags: xsd, wsdl, rename, gsoap

I'm creating web service by gSoap, using existing WSDL and the necessary schemas as argument for the command `wsdl2h`.

I have in my schema the element **i_ID** declared this way :

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="i_ID" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
```

But **gSoap** rename the attribute to **i_USCOREID** :

```
/// Element i_ID of type xs:string.
    char*                                i_USCOREID
```

And I noticed it happens the same for all the fields after each `_`.

Do you know guys how to fix this? Because this reduces the readablity and I'm not right to change the **.XSD file**. Maybe I should add an option to the command `wsdl2h`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

use the "-_" flag when using the wsdl2h

"-_      don't generate _USCORE (replace with UNICODE _x005f)"

Comment: Can you tell me how to use this flag? I'm under VisualStudio. Thank you